# how do you automate test a enterprise security software application?

Tags: automated-testing, test-management

I have been assigned to automate test a enterprise security software which will be installed on client computers with different operating systems (linux, windows).
my team challenge is to setup a proper infrastructure and ci/cd technologies for automate testing of such software which do various things like encrypting/decrypting the client disk in boot time, monitoring network activities, watching the filesystem, popping up windows for alerts and etc.. and all of these things are seems hard to be automate for testing.

does any one have experience in automate testing a software with these capabilities that can share with me ?

the acceptance test of this software is gonna be written in cucumber framework and I'm writing a system to run these tests on different virtual machines with different operating system through ssh connection. one of the challenges is to run these tests in parallel in many machines with different virtualization technologies(Vmware, Kvm/Libvirt) and these machines should be in proper state for running the tests.
do you think a technology like ansible can help with this ? and what other technologies and practices can help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "**Ansible** is the solution:

- Installation to different operating systems
- For testing purpose, you can write different playbooks pertaining to your requirements
- Facilitate to connect to different operating systems (Winrm for windows, SSH for linux machines.

You can have a look to this:
[https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/overview_architecture.html#:~:text=Ansible%20is%20a%20radically%20simple,and%20many%20other%20IT%20needs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/overview_architecture.html#:%7E:text=Ansible%20is%20a%20radically%20simple,and%20many%20other%20IT%20needs).